# How to call a specific element from a specific column in dataframe in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data set (dimension is 6x3) looks like:

```
#pollution
#      city  size amount
#1 New York large     23
#2 New York small     14
#3   London large     22
#4   London small     16
#5  Beijing large    121
#6  Beijing small     56
```

With the following code, I try to call the amount of every city whose size is large, expecting it will print: 23, 22, 121.

`pollution$city[1,3,5]`

but it failed due to the incorrect number of dimension.

I know I can call specific column or row by using select() or slice() but I don't know how to call the values (either numeric or character) from specific column or specific row. Could you let me know how to fix `pollution$city[1,3,5]` to get 23,22,121?

Comment: `pollution$city[c(1,3,5)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#1
pollution$amount[c(1,3,5)]

#2
pollution[pollution$size=="large","amount"]

#3
library(dplyr)
filter(pollution, size=="large") %>%
  pull(amount)
```